# The volume boot has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

Tags: apt, disk-usage

I've seen the thread to counter this issue (can't link it because the two pictures below is my limit apparently) and even successfully ran through it in the past. However this time the commands aren't working. It appears that I need dependencies for some reason:

[image: dependency errors]

At first I thought it wasn't an issue but after purging all extra dependencies then running `autoclean`/`autoremove`, I realized it indeed did nothing. I've also tried to run `apt-get -f install` as suggested to no luck. I'm greeted the standard y/n install prompt. When I type y and continue, this is eventually displayed:

[image: apt install -f]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your terminal (unless there's something that only a screenshot can show) - just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code using the `{}` button - that way the text is searchable

Comment: can you do a `ls -lh /boot` and `df -h`.  Then post the output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to free up some space on your /boot partition before you can do anything.

`ls -lh /boot` and look for large files to delete, but be careful not to delete your any of the kernels that you need.

Once you have deleted some of the kernel files that you **do not need** you should be able to run `apt-get autoremove`

Again do not delete your running kernel files, or the newest kernel files.  If you do, you will render your computer unbootable.

Good luck.